# Using Attr Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in a situation

I am appending a button to a div, which has a width

```
  $('#main').append('<button id="hello" type="button" style="width:100px">Click Me!</button>');
```

I am trying to change the width however nothing happens

```
$("#main").prop({ width: '300px'});
```

Ive tried using .css , .attr and .width to try changing the width however the same problem keeps happening. I am still not sure why this is happening even after googling, if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to change the width of the element with ID `main`, or the width of the button? `.width(300)` should work just fine, either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to set the width of the button, you've got to select the button, not the div.

```
$('#hello').width(300);
```

([Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/yT9eS/))

If your goal is to set the width immediately after `.append()`ing, you're better off just starting with the right width:

```
$('#main').append($('<button/>', {
    id: 'hello',
    text: 'Click Me!',
    width: 300
}));
```

([Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/N6g7x/))

---

Read up on `.width()`: http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2 (Yes, the jQuery API docs are down right now.)

Comment: I spotted after a about an hour of looking at my code, I used a variable to choose the button: $(myvar)  however I forgot to put the "#" infront. I kept on overlooking that part every time then thought that there must be some problems with setting width of buttons in jQuery. Gah!! Thanks very much though!

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the width of the element holding it, don't you want to change the width of the button? Also jQuery has a width method.

```
$("#hello").width(300);
//or
$("#main").find("button").width(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the `#main` div or the `#hello` button?

DIV:

```
$("#main").css('width', '300px');
```

BUTTON:

```
$("#hello").css('width', '300px');
```

I know you said that you have used the .css method, but it should be working.  If it's still not working you might put up an example in jsfiddle so we can see better.